# Spark - Group by Key then Count by Value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, key-value

I have non-unique key-value pairs that I have created using the `map` function from an `RDD Array[String]`

```
val kvPairs = myRdd.map(line => (line(0), line(1)))
```

This produces data of format:

```
1, A
1, A
1, B
2, C
```

I would like to group all of they keys by their values and provide the counts for these values like so:

```
1, {(A, 2), (B, 1)}
2, {(C, 1)}
```

I have tried many different attempts, but the closest I can get is with something like this:

```
kvPairs.sortByKey().countByValue()
```

This gives

```
1, (A, 2)
1, (B, 1)
2, (C, 1)
```

Also,

```
kvPairs.groupByKey().sortByKey()
```

Provides value, but it still isn't quite there:

```
1, {(A, A, B)}
2, {(C)}
```

I tried combining the two together:

```
kvPairs.countByValue().groupByKey().sortByKey()
```

But this return an error

> error: value groupByKey is not a member of scala.collection.Map[(String, String),Long]

Comment: countByValue() returns a map, groupByKey is a method on an RDD - you cannot use it on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just count pairs directly and group (if you have to) afterwards:

```
kvPairs.map((_, 1L))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map{ case ((k, v), cnt) => (k, (v, cnt)) }
  .groupByKey
```

If you want to `gropuByKey` after reducing you may want to use custom partitioner which considers only the first element of the key. You can check [RDD split and do aggregation on new RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35084175/1560062) for an example implementation.