# Spark simpler value_counts

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Something similar to [Spark - Group by Key then Count by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763284/spark-group-by-key-then-count-by-value) would allow me to emulate `df.series.value_counts()` the functionality of Pandas in Spark to:

> The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first
>   element is the most frequently-occurring element. Excludes NA values
>   by default. (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

I am curious if this can't be achieved nicer / simpler for data frames in Spark.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is just a basic aggregation, isn't it?

```
df.groupBy($"value").count.orderBy($"count".desc)
```

Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]).value_counts()
```

```
2    3
3    2
4    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Spark SQL:

```scala
Seq(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4).toDF("value")
  .groupBy($"value").count.orderBy($"count".desc)
```

```
+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|    2|    3|
|    3|    2|
|    1|    1|
|    4|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

If you want to include additional grouping columns (like "key") just put these in the `groupBy`:

```
df.groupBy($"key", $"value").count.orderBy($"count".desc)
```

Comment: Im trying to use this in a udf to apply this for each row of a dask dataframe, however when I define the UDF Im getting an error in the syntax due to the $ symbol